# python return double entry in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, maya

I am searching for hours and hours on this problem and tried everything possible but I can't get it cracked, I am quiet a dictionary noob.

I work with maya and got clashing names of lights, this happens when you duplicate a group all children are named the same as before, so having a ALL_KEY in one group results in a clashing name with a key_char in another group.

I need to identify a clashing name of the short name and return the long name so I can do a print long name is double or even a cmds.select.
Unfortunately everything I find on this matter in the internet is about returning if a list contains double values or not and only returns True or False, which is useless for me, so I tried list cleaning and list comparison, but I get stuck with a dictionary to maintain long and short names at the same time.
I managed to fetch short names if they are duplicates and return them, but on the way the long name got lost, so of course I can't identify it clearly anymore.

```
>import itertools 
>import fnmatch 
>import maya.cmds as mc 
>LIGHT_TYPES = ["spotLight", "areaLight", "directionalLight", "pointLight", "aiAreaLight", "aiPhotometricLight", "aiSkyDomeLight"]


#create dict
dblList = {'long' : 'short'}
for x in mc.ls (type=LIGHT_TYPES, transforms=True):
    y = x.split('|')[-1:][0]
    dblList['long','short'] = dblList.setdefault(x, y)



#reverse values with keys for easier detection
rev_multidict = {}
for key, value in dblList.items():
    rev_multidict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

#detect the doubles in the dict
#print [values for key, values in rev_multidict.items() if len(values) > 1]
flattenList = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(values for key, values in rev_multidict.items() if len(values) > 1))

#so by now I got all the long names which clash in the scene already!
#means now I just need to make a for loop strip away the pipes and ask if the object is already in the list, then return the path with the pipe, and ask if the object is in lightlist and return the longname if so.
#but after many many hours I can't get this part working.
##as example until now print flattenList returns
>set([u'ALL_blockers|ALL_KEY', u'ABCD_0140|scSet', u'SARAH_TOPShape', u'ABCD_0140|scChars', u'ALL|ALL_KEY', u'|scChars', u'|scSet', u'|scFX', ('long', 'short'), u'ABCD_0140|scFX'])

#we see ALL_KEY is double! and that's exactly what I need returned as long name

#THIS IS THE PART THAT I CAN'T GET WORKING, CHECK IN THE LIST WHICH VALUES ARE DOUBLE IN THE LONGNAME AND RETURN THE SHORTNAME LIST.
THE WHOLE DICTIONARY IS STILL COMPLETE AS 
seen = set()
uniq = []
for x in dblList2:
    if x[0].split('|')[-1:][0] not in seen:
        uniq.append(x.split('|')[-1:][0])
        seen.add(x.split('|')[-1:][0])
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: I just want to point out that this: `dblList['long','short'] = dblList.setdefault(x, y)` willl result in a dict that looks like: `{'long': 'short', ('long', 'short'): y, x: y}`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: no but I don't know how else to fill a dictionary, It's my first time.

Comment: Please edit your question with your desired output. It's going to  be difficult to help you if I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. In the meantime please read more about how dictionaries work [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: please read my text again. I can't describe it more detailed other than maybe making a scientific whitepaper about my question. Sure I'll read the dictionary thingie.

Comment: So are you just trying to get the new long names of objects that don't have unique short names?

Comment: What you have is an XY problem. You are trying to find the clashing names instead of just fixing whatever is giving you clashing names. Stop focusing on your "solution" and begin addressing the problem. What does your dictionary need to look like? What settings are you trying to use? It seems like you don't understand how dictionaries work at all so it's going to be very difficult to help you if we don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok, again. I am not sure if it is the best approach (just for the people who try to insult me soon) It is not my mistake that there are clashing names, I am trying to prevent usererror with my script.

I don't really know how to explain what I need because the system of maya is not easy to understand if you don't know the software + I am not sure what python would be easiest to achieve that:

basically I need a dict: {'':  u'ALL|ALL_KEY' : u'ALL_KEY', u'BOUNCE:JUNE_blockers|BOUNCE:JUNE_BLK_RIM_table': u'BOUNCE:JUNE_BLK_RIM_table', u'JUNE_blockers|JUNE_BLK_FILL_table': u'JUNE_BLK_FILL_table'}

Comment: this was an example and it shows you on the left side the long name (with the pipe character '|' and on the right side the short name, now If I look in the list of the short name and I see two times for example 'ALL_KEY' in that list, he should return simply one time the long name of u'ALL|ALL_KEY' so I can say print 'light %s exists twice in your scene, please fix' %u'ALL|ALL_KEY'  (of course that all key will be inside an var later)

Comment: So you want a dictionary like this `{<long name>:<short name>}` of objects with duplicate names..? Sorry, like IanAuld I'm a bit unclear of what you're after.

Comment: now why do I need to compare the shortnames and can't work with the longnames, because one string might look like this 'u'JUNE_blockers|ALL_KEY', and the next string like this u'ALL|ALL_KEY' as you see the two objects don't look alike and the list suddenly doesn't have double entries anymore, only the shortlist version shows double entries. and that's what I need to detect and then get the longname for it. I thought Dictionaries are wise for that kind of situation, but I simply don't know how to do the for loop to keep track of both lists with it's equal values side a side at the same time.

Comment: To help you we really need to see what your input is, what your desired output is vs. what you are actually getting and any errors you get along the way.

Comment: I'd wanted to give an answer but your question is so unclear I have no idea what you're trying to do. We can still help, but tell us what you're hoping the final output to be. My guess is this:

`{'': u'ALL|ALL_KEY' : u'ALL_KEY', u'BOUNCE:JUNE_blockers|BOUNCE:JUNE_BLK_RIM_table': u'BOUNCE:JUNE_BLK_RIM_table', u'JUNE_blockers|JUNE_BLK_FILL_table': u'JUNE_BLK_FILL_table'}`

I still don't understand the need for a dictionary either.

And if duplicate names are a problem, is there a reason that PyMel is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab with this. If this isn't what you want let me know why.

If I have a scene with a hierarchy like this:

```
group1
  nurbsCircle1
group2
  nurbsCircle2
group3
  nurbsCircle1
```

I can run this (adjust `ls()` if you need it for selection or whatnot):

```
conflictObjs = {}
objs = cmds.ls(shortNames = True, transforms = True)
for obj in objs:
    if len( obj.split('|') ) > 1:
        conflictObjs[obj] = obj.split('|')[-1]
```

And the output of `conflictObjs` will be:

```
# Dictionary of objects with non-unique short names
# {<long name>:<short name>}
{u'group1|nurbsCircle1': u'nurbsCircle1', u'group3|nurbsCircle1': u'nurbsCircle1'}
```

Showing me what objects don't have unique short names.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the lights which have duplicate short names, grouped by what the duplicated name is and including the full path of the duplicated objects:

```
def clashes_by_type(*types):
    long_names = cmds.ls(type = types, l=True) or []
    # get the parents from the lights, not using ls -type transform
    long_names = set(cmds.listRelatives(*long_names, p=True, f=True) or [])
    short_names = set([i.rpartition("|")[-1] for i in long_names])
    short_dict = dict()
    for sn in short_names:
        short_dict[sn] = [i for i in long_names if i.endswith("|"+ sn)]
    clashes = dict((k,v) for k, v in short_dict.items() if len(v) > 1)
    return clashes

clashes_by_type('directionalLight', 'ambientLight')The main points to note:
```

1. work down from long names. short names are inherently unreliable!
2. when deriving the short names, include the last pipe so you don't get accidental overlaps of common names
3. `short_names` will always be a list of lists since it's created by a comprehension
4. once you have a dict of (name, [objects with that shortname]) it's easy to get clashes by looking for values longer than 1